# Laravel exec() produce a mysql-dump empty file

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, xampp

I'm using exec() for execute mysql-dump but it's generating an empty file on apache, but when i use the "php artisan serve" the file is generated correctly, the output file has the same user and group in apache and in the artisan serve.

Using: Ubuntu 14.04 and Xamp 5.6.12

```
$dir = substr(__DIR__, 0, 24).'database/backups/';

$newBackup = Backup::create();

$command = 'mysqldump -uroot lions > '.$dir.$newBackup->getDateTimeString().'.sql';

exec($command);
```

Comment: echo the $command and see what it is, check if folder is writable, there should be a missed spot

Comment: the command works perfect with the "artisan server" and generate a correctly file (with data), but when i try in apache just generate a empty file and the folder is writable because the command creates the file but not the data (0 bytes)

Comment: Try fetching the output and exit code from `exec` and log them, so you can see if the command was run successfully. Just use `exec($command, $output, $exitCode);`. Maybe it's something to do with user permissions, since the `artisan serve` command will have your user permission, while the other will have Apache's.

Comment: Apache { "output": [], "exitCode": 127 }
Artisan { "output": [], "exitCode": 0 }

Comment: That means file not found. Instead of mysqldump try with full PATH

Comment: Exit code 127 means **Command not found**. As @72DFBF5BA0DF5BE9 suggested you should try running the command with a full path to the `mysqldump` binary. You can find the path by running `locate mysqldump` (if you're on Ubuntu that's probably `/usr/bin/mysqldump`).

Comment: that works! $command = '/opt/lampp/bin/mysqldump ...

Comment: If this is your dev environment, then the path might be different on your production server and this solution will not work there. If that's the case, you can append `/opt/lampp/bin/` to the `PATH` variable in the `envvars` file. Generally that's in `/etc/apache/envvars`, but since I see you're using XAMPP I think it's in `/opt/lampp/bin/envvars`. (you'll also have to do this on your server).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I was facing the same problem with Laravel 5.6 and running windows though. Before anything, you should make sure to include the password argument (either as `--password` or `-p`), even if its empty.

```
$cmd =
"mysqldump -h " . env('DB_HOST') .
" -u "          . env('DB_USERNAME') .
" -p\""         . env('DB_PASSWORD') . "\"" .
" --databases " . env('DB_DATABASE');
```

The main issue is that even though several sources note that `exec` waits until the process is complete there is no way to know for sure, leaving that aside, since processes could be owned by different users it'd probably be better if you created a temporary file and then flashed the contents of the output array into it rather than hoping for `mysqldump` to do it for you.

```
$output = [];
$name = "your_random_file_name.sql";

exec($cmd, $output);

$tmppath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), $name);
$handle = fopen($tmppath, "w");
fwrite($handle, implode($output, "\n"));
```

Finally, write the main file to your desired location, in my case I upload it directly to an `Amazon S3 bucket`, and close the temporary file.

```
Storage::disk('myS3bucket')
->putFileAs("backups", new File($tmppath), $name);
fclose($handle);
```

I know it seems redundant but, as I mentioned above, there is no way to know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, in a development environment, it is customary not to set a password for the database. And that's why your command does not work.

But in a production environment, you are obliged to set a password for the database.

Try in your production environment (**ie with a password!**), And you will see that the script works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution for this problem but I do know it should be possible to do this. If I enter the following command in my terminal the mysqldump works:

```
mysqldump "--user=root" "--password=" dbname > ~/Desktop/export.sql
```

But when I use this command in my scheduler as below, I gett an empty file.

```
$schedule->exec("mysqldump \"--user=".env('DB_USERNAME')."\" \"--password=".env('DB_PASSWORD')."\" ".env('DB_DATABASE')." > export.sql")->everyMinute();
```

Maybe there is someone who knows why this doesn't work? I'm guessing it's a permission issue, but I leak experience in this.